# Stopping a server in a subprocess with its shutdown method

Tags: python, server, multiprocessing, shutdown

I am implementing a `Server` class in CPython 3.7 on Windows 10 with a `Server.serve` method that starts the serving forever and a `Server.shutdown` method that stops the serving. I need to run multiple server instances in subprocesses.

Running a server instance in a subthread stops the instance as expected:

```
import threading
import time


class Server:

    def __init__(self):
        self.shutdown_request = False

    def serve(self):
        print("serving")

        while not self.shutdown_request:
            print("hello")
            time.sleep(1)

        print("done")

    def shutdown(self):
        print("stopping")
        self.shutdown_request = True


if __name__ == "__main__":
    server = Server()
    threading.Thread(target=server.serve).start()
    time.sleep(5)
    server.shutdown()
```

However running a server instance in a subprocess does not stop the instance, unexpectedly:

```
import multiprocessing
import time


class Server:

    def __init__(self):
        self.shutdown_request = False

    def serve(self):
        print("serving")

        while not self.shutdown_request:
            print("hello")
            time.sleep(1)

        print("done")

    def shutdown(self):
        print("stopping")
        self.shutdown_request = True


if __name__ == "__main__":
    server = Server()
    multiprocessing.Process(target=server.serve).start()
    time.sleep(5)
    server.shutdown()
```

I suspect that in the multiprocessing case, the `self.shutdown_request` attribute is not shared between the parent process and the subprocess, and therefore the `server.shutdown()` call does not affect the running server instance in the subprocess.

I know I could solve this with `multiprocessing.Event`:

```
import multiprocessing
import time


class Server:

    def __init__(self, shutdown_event):
        self.shutdown_event = shutdown_event

    def serve(self):
        print("serving")

        while not self.shutdown_event.is_set():
            print("hello")
            time.sleep(1)

        print("done")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    shutdown_event = multiprocessing.Event()
    server = Server(shutdown_event)
    multiprocessing.Process(target=server.serve).start()
    time.sleep(5)
    shutdown_event.set()
```

But I want to keep the `Server.shutdown` method instead of changing the `Server` interface according to its usage (single processing *v.* multiprocessing) and I don't want clients to deal with `multiprocessing.Event`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finally figured out a solution by myself:

```
import multiprocessing
import time


class Server:

    def __init__(self):
        self.shutdown_event = multiprocessing.Event()

    def serve(self):
        print("serving")

        while not self.shutdown_event.is_set():
            print("hello")
            time.sleep(1)

        print("done")

    def shutdown(self):
        print("stopping")
        self.shutdown_event.set()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    server = Server()
    multiprocessing.Process(target=server.serve).start()
    time.sleep(5)
    server.shutdown()
```

It works in either case: single processing (multithreading) and multiprocessing.

*Remark.* — With a `multiprocessing.Event()` in the `__init__` method, `Server` instances are no longer pickable. That might be a problem if one wants to call a `Server` instance in a process pool (either with `multiprocessing.pool.Pool` or `concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor`). In this case, one should replace `multiprocessing.Event()` with `multiprocessing.Manager().Event()` in the `__init__` method.